# zsh / zle Editing long commands, specifically trying to insert characters, garbles the command string

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

tmux, zsh, vi mode, oh-my-zsh, TERM set to screen-256color 
I scroll through command history with Esc K, on each command i can move left and right, and i can erase characters, but as soon as I try to insert the command string gets garbled. Also,this only happens when the command is longer then the terminal width.

zshrc:
    export ZSH=${HOME}/.oh-my-zsh

```
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell-ay"

CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

plugins=(git)

if [ -f $HOME/.aliases ]; then
  source $HOME/.aliases
fi

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

if [ -f $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh ]; then
  source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
fi

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

export KEYTIMEOUT=1

setopt nosharehistory

bindkey -v

PATH=$PATH:${HOME}/bin
export PATH="$HOME/.plenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(plenv init - zsh)"`
```

prompt is set in "robbyrussell-ay":

```
local ret_status="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"

PROMPT=$'[%D{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}]$fg[cyan][%n@%m]$reset_color $fg[yellow]%~ $fg[green]$(git_prompt_info)\n${ret_status}${reset_color} '


ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg_bold[blue]%}git:(%{$fg[red]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%} "
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}) %{$fg[yellow]%}✗"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[blue]%})"
```

Comment: Do you actually use `screen` or `tmux`? If so, which one? If not `TERM` should not be `screen-256color`. In case of `tmux`: do you set `TERM` in the `tmux` configuration (`~/.tmux.conf`) or the `zsh` configuration? It should be the first one, setting `TERM` in the shell configuration is almost always wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Adaephon, I do use tmux, TERM is set in ~/.tmux.conf `set-option -g default-terminal screen-256color`

Comment: Post your complete `.zshrc` and any files it includes. Often the problem is a prompt that's missing `%{…%}` around zero-width sequences. And do this on [unix.se], this site is about programming.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, i had an error in my prompt -

```
PROMPT=$'[%D{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}]$fg[cyan][%n@%m]$reset_color $fg[yellow]%~ $fg[green]$(git_prompt_info)\n${ret_status}${reset_color} '
```

had a section that should have been wrapped in %{...%}

```
$fg[cyan][%n@%m]
```

should be

```
%{fg[cyan]%}[%n@%m]
```

I ended up changing my prompt slightly, it now looks like this:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg[yellow]%}[%*|%D]%}${ret_status}%{$fg[cyan]%}[%n@%m]$reset_color%{$fg[cyan]%}%~%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info)
```

$ '